# Is it possible to put an id and a <?php echo ''.$variable.''; ?> on the same input tag or video tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to put this **Ids** into a single `video` input tag. I need to put `player` and its row ids which is in `php` I've done it this way

Though it didnt work, but am i missing something or what? thank you here is my code

```
 <video preload controls playsinline id="player[<?php echo ''.$row5['id'].'';?>]" width="100%"></video>
```

the **`<?php echo ''.$row5['id'].'';?>`** is get from this code `data-id` attribute

**Code**

```
<div data-id="<?php echo ''.$row5['id'].'';?>"><img src="images/gems.png" width="33px"></div>
```

So this is how it works, when the image is clicked then the video should play its id depending on the id of what the image is.

I just need to work it done together with the `player` id because without it the video wouldnt play.

Javascript Code

```
    var episodeid = $(this).data('id');
          var pelement = document.getElementById(episodeid);
           $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "check-series.php",
                  data: {episodeid:episodeid},
                  dataType: "text",
                  async: false,
                  success: function(data) {

            if(data == '1'){
              if (pelement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
               $("#myModal2").show();
              }
              else if (pelement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                $("#myModal2").show();
              }
              document.getElementById(episodeid).play();
              }
 else {
              $.confirm({
                title: 'Purchase episode?',
                content: 'You are about to buy ' + episodetitle + '.' ,
                theme: 'supervan',
                buttons: {
                    confirm: function () {
                      $.alert('Proceeding to payments page..');
                      window.location.href = "paymentmethod.php?id=" + episodeid;
                    },
                    cancel: function () {
                        $.alert('You have cancelled your purchase!');
                    }
                }
          });



                  }
                },
                  error: function(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  }
                });



          });
```

Comment: Why do you concatenate empty strings in the `echo` statement? I've seen people do this before, but they never explain why.

Comment: What is the problem you're having? If `data-id` is supposed to match the ID of the video, then it should be `data-id="player[<?php echo ''.$row5['id'].'';?>]"`

Comment: Dump the variable and see what happens - `var_dump($row5);`

Comment: Barmar , to make it clear it should be like this `<video preload controls playsinline id="player <?php echo ''.$row5['id'].'';?>" width="100%"></video>`

Comment: Why not just `<?php echo $row5['id']?>`? What's the purpose of `''.$row5['id'].''`?

Comment: @Qirel , when I dont click the image , it is null but when I click it is `131` which is correct because it fetch the correct video id number

Comment: @Barmar , when I remove the `player` then it works good changing to `echo $row5['id']` did not work sir :( sorry. but removing the player works but I need the player :(

Comment: I never said anything about removing `player`.

Comment: There's no difference between `<?php echo ''.$row5['id'].'';?>` and `<?php echo $row5['id'];?>`. How can concatenating empty strings to something make a difference?

Comment: You need to show the JavaScript code that makes use of `data-id`, so we can see how it looks for the video player.

Comment: Please note that my comments about the empty strings has nothing to do with the problem you're asking about, it's just a general issue about code quality.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to put square brackets in IDs. Square brackets have special meaning in selectors, and if the code that looks for the ID doesn't escape them it might not work.

Comment: When you say 'did not work' what did it do?

Comment: @Barmar - I've added the javascript code

Comment: @ryantxr - I've added the javascript code so as you can see whn the data is found then the modal with video player  wll show

Comment: @Barmar  as you can see whn the data is found then the modal with video player wll show

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test and your code works.

```
<?php $row5['id'] = 123; ?>

<video preload controls playsinline id="player[<?php echo ''.$row5['id'].'';?>]" width="100%"></video>
```

Outputs:

```
<video preload controls playsinline id="player[123]" width="100%"></video>
```

Setting the value to null still works, even if the extra '' quotes are removed. You don't need them.

```
<?php $row5['id'] = null; ?>

<video preload controls playsinline id="player[<?php echo ''.$row5['id'].'';?>]" width="100%"></video>
<video preload controls playsinline id="player[<?php echo $row5['id'];?>]" width="100%"></video>
```

Output:

```
<video preload controls playsinline id="player[]" width="100%"></video>
<video preload controls playsinline id="player[]" width="100%"></video>
```

Comment: really? i dont know why it is not working on my end :(

Comment: however  when I remove the `player` the modal with video shows up

Comment: What modal? You didn't say anything about a modal.

Comment: yep its just a modal.. just the video player lets just say it that way

Answer (score 0):

Your video has an ID like `id="player[123]"`. But in the DIV you have `data-id="123"`. You're not putting `player[]` around the ID number in the `data-id` attribute. Change the DIV to:

```
<div data-id="player[<?php echo $row5['id'];?>]"><img src="images/gems.png" width="33px"></div>
```

so the value of `data-id` matches the full ID of the video.